# How to divide two columns?

Tags: sql

I tried to divide two columns from joined tables but the result (value of column relative_duration) is always 0. The query is the following:

```
    SELECT t1.[user_1]
      ,t1.[user_2]
      ,t1.[total_duration]
      ,(t1.total_duration/t2.[total_events_duration]) AS relative_duration
  FROM [CDRs].[dbo].[aggregate_monthly_events] AS t1 INNER JOIN [CDRs].[dbo].[user_events_monthly_stats] AS t2 ON t1.[user_1] = t2.[user_1]
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong in the query above and how to fix it in order to divide column total_duration from table t1 with column total_events_duration from table t2?

BTW I tried to replace division with subtraction ("/" with "-") and in that case the column relative_duration is not 0.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Presumably, those columns are integer columns - which will be the reason as the result of the calculation will be of the same type.

e.g. if you do this:

```
SELECT 1 / 2
```

you will get 0, which is obviously not the real answer.
So, convert the values to e.g. decimal and do the calculation based on that datatype instead.

e.g.

```
SELECT CAST(1 AS DECIMAL) / 2
```

gives 0.500000

Comment: Worked perfectly after I got my eyes strained for 1 hour looking for a solution. Kudos!