# dividing values of 2 columns

Tags: sql

How can I divide the values of 2 columns?

```
select column1, column2, (column1 / column2) as %ofSales ------
```

won't work for me.

Comment: "wont work" - what do you mean by that? You get an incorrect result? You get an error? You're fundamentally opposed to the use of the `/` character? I'd suggest you [edit] your question and add some *sample data* and *expected results*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to divide two columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996779/how-to-divide-two-columns)

Comment: error. what should i use?

Comment: What error? also possible that `column2` have 0 as value?

Comment: you're still not helping @wilmer Ong. you are probably getting a syntax eror. see my answer below.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: invalid column name 'CONSIGNMENT'. i have a consignment column but its pivoted from a single column (From a combobox)

Answer (score 0):

Your query have not from clase

```
select column1, column2, (column1 / column2) as %ofSale
from my_table
```

and could be that the as column name with %  should be wrapped  in quotes

```
select column1, column2, (column1 / column2) as '%ofSale'
from my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting a syntax error. Try with apostrophes like below

```
select column1, column2, (column1 / column2) as '%ofSales'
from yourTable
```

Comment: invalid column name 'CONSIGNMENT'. i have a column for consignment but its pivoted from a single column (from a combobox)

Comment: consignment is just my alias

Comment: can you give the whole query ? or better, fiddle it at http://sqlfiddle.com/ ? because error and the part of code you share is irrelevant.

Comment: SELECT     dbo.RtlStore.Description, COUNT(CASE WHEN dbo.InvProduct.U_OwnershipType = N'CONSIGNMENT' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS CONSIGNMENT,  COUNT(CASE WHEN dbo.InvProduct.U_OwnershipType = N'OUTRIGHT' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS OUTRIGHT,  COUNT(CASE WHEN dbo.InvProduct.U_OwnershipType = N'HOUSEBRAND' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS HOURSEBRAND, COUNT(CASE WHEN dbo.InvProduct.U_OwnershipType = N'GOI' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS GOI, COUNT(CASE WHEN dbo.InvProduct.U_OwnershipType = N'OTHERS' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS OTHERS, COUNT(dbo.InvProduct.U_OwnershipType) AS Total

Comment: FROM         dbo.TrxTransaction INNER JOIN
                      dbo.RtlStore ON dbo.TrxTransaction.StoreKey = dbo.RtlStore.StoreKey INNER JOIN
                      dbo.InvProduct INNER JOIN
                      dbo.TrxTransactionSaleItem ON dbo.InvProduct.ProductKey = dbo.TrxTransactionSaleItem.ProductKey ON dbo.TrxTransaction.TransactionKey = dbo.TrxTransactionSaleItem.TransactionKey

GROUP BY dbo.RtlStore.Description

Comment: @wilmerOng - please **edit** your question and add your complete query. Code in comments is practically unreadable, whereas in your question you can highlight the whole block and hit the `{}` button and it maintains whitespace/layout and even turns on syntax highlighting. Whilst you're editing please also consider my request that you add *sample data* and *expected results*.